# error in R In serialize(data, node$con) : 'package:stats' may not be available when loading

Tags: r, statistics

Im using IPO to optimize xcms

````
```
library(IPO)
```

Carregando pacotes exigidos: xcms
Carregando pacotes exigidos: BiocParallel
Carregando pacotes exigidos: MSnbase
Carregando pacotes exigidos: BiocGenerics

Attaching package: ‘BiocGenerics’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    IQR, mad, sd, var, xtabs

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    anyDuplicated, append, as.data.frame, basename, cbind, colnames, dirname, do.call, duplicated, eval,
    evalq, Filter, Find, get, grep, grepl, intersect, is.unsorted, lapply, Map, mapply, match, mget, order,
    paste, pmax, pmax.int, pmin, pmin.int, Position, rank, rbind, Reduce, rownames, sapply, setdiff, sort,
    table, tapply, union, unique, unsplit, which.max, which.min

Carregando pacotes exigidos: Biobase
Welcome to Bioconductor

    Vignettes contain introductory material; view with 'browseVignettes()'. To cite Bioconductor, see
    'citation("Biobase")', and for packages 'citation("pkgname")'.

Carregando pacotes exigidos: mzR
Carregando pacotes exigidos: Rcpp
Carregando pacotes exigidos: S4Vectors
Carregando pacotes exigidos: stats4

Attaching package: ‘S4Vectors’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    expand.grid, I, unname

Carregando pacotes exigidos: ProtGenerics

Attaching package: ‘ProtGenerics’

The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:

    smooth


This is MSnbase version 2.22.0 
  Visit https://lgatto.github.io/MSnbase/ to get started.


Attaching package: ‘MSnbase’

The following object is masked from ‘package:base’:

    trimws


This is xcms version 3.18.0 


Attaching package: ‘xcms’

The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:

    sigma

Carregando pacotes exigidos: rsm
Carregando pacotes exigidos: CAMERA

Attaching package: ‘IPO’

The following object is masked from ‘package:S4Vectors’:

    decode

> mzdatafiles<-list.files(recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE)
> peakpickingParameters<-getDefaultXcmsSetStartingParams('centWave')
> peakpickingParameters$min_peakwidth<-c(10,20)
> peakpickingParameters$max_peakwidth<-c(26,42)
> peakpickingParameters$ppm<-20
> time.xcmsSet <- system.time
> 
> resultPeakpickingPOS<-optimizeXcmsSet(files=mzdatafiles,params=peakpickingParameters,nSlaves=1,subdir='rsmDirectory')



starting new DoE with:
min_peakwidth: c(10, 20)
max_peakwidth: c(26, 42)
ppm: 20
mzdiff: c(-0.001, 0.01)
snthresh: 10
noise: 0
prefilter: 3
value_of_prefilter: 100
mzCenterFun: wMean
integrate: 1
fitgauss: FALSE
verbose.columns: FALSE

1
Carregando pacotes exigidos: xcms
Carregando pacotes exigidos: BiocParallel
Carregando pacotes exigidos: MSnbase
Carregando pacotes exigidos: BiocGenerics

Attaching package: ‘BiocGenerics’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    IQR, mad, sd, var, xtabs

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    anyDuplicated, append, as.data.frame, basename, cbind, colnames, dirname, do.call, duplicated, eval,
    evalq, Filter, Find, get, grep, grepl, intersect, is.unsorted, lapply, Map, mapply, match, mget, order,
    paste, pmax, pmax.int, pmin, pmin.int, Position, rank, rbind, Reduce, rownames, sapply, setdiff, sort,
    table, tapply, union, unique, unsplit, which.max, which.min

Carregando pacotes exigidos: Biobase
Welcome to Bioconductor

    Vignettes contain introductory material; view with 'browseVignettes()'. To cite Bioconductor, see
    'citation("Biobase")', and for packages 'citation("pkgname")'.

Carregando pacotes exigidos: mzR
Carregando pacotes exigidos: Rcpp
Carregando pacotes exigidos: S4Vectors
Carregando pacotes exigidos: stats4

Attaching package: ‘S4Vectors’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    expand.grid, I, unname

Carregando pacotes exigidos: ProtGenerics

Attaching package: ‘ProtGenerics’

The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:

    smooth


This is MSnbase version 2.22.0 
  Visit https://lgatto.github.io/MSnbase/ to get started.


Attaching package: ‘MSnbase’

The following object is masked from ‘package:base’:

    trimws


This is xcms version 3.18.0 


Attaching package: ‘xcms’

The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:

    sigma


Stop worker failed with the error: wrong args for environment subassignment
Warning messages:
1: In serialize(data, node$con) :
  'package:stats' may not be available when loading
2: In serialize(data, node$con) :
  'package:stats' may not be available when loading
````

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `nSlaves` argument means it's trying to spawn a new R process and for a variety of possible reasons, the new R process is likely looking in a different location for the R libraries than in your main R process.

You might want to try setting `nSlaves = 0` so that it doesn't spawn a new process and does the work in your existing R process where those libraries exist. Since you only put in `1`, I'm assuming you aren't really interested in the parallel processing aspect.

If you do want to use parallel processing, it looks like you will need to look at the `BPPARAM` argument for `optimizeXcmsSet` for setting specific `BioParallel` parameters to manage parallel processing configuration.